# check compatability of a shared library before dynamically loading it

Tags: c, linux, linker, dynamic-linking

I have a program and bunch of "plug-ins" (shared libraries) that the main program loads on request during the runtime.

The plug-ins can access all the internal global data-structures/functions of the program, so there is no option to keep version for each time the internal data-structures changed.

I'm seeking for a way, that the main program can check if the plug-in it tries to load is supported (uses the appropriate data-structures).

Is there a creative way you can think of, doing this?

Comment: Export a getVersion function from the library - load, call it, determine compatibility based on this version.

Answer (score 2):

Have a function in the plugin returns information about the version of the protocol its support (The protocol of a plugin isn't restricted to what it provides, it is also what is required from the calling program.)

Answer (score 0):

AProgrammer's answer (or simply exporting a global variable with the version number) will work, but bear in mind that no solution is foolproof or safe against malicious plugin files. Loaded modules run in the same memory space as your program, with the same privileges, and unfortunately the dynamic loader will happily run global constructors in the plugin before you are able to query the version or perform any checking yourself. (*Grumble* anyone have a link to Global Constructors Considered Harmful?)

In any case, if the plugin architecture is your design, I would highly recommend you ban any use of global constructors in specification for plugins. Of course you can't enforce this at runtime, but at least then you can blame any plugin author who breaks things for violating the contract.

Comment: If you want to protect against malicious user provided code, you'll want to run that code in a virtual machine.